# How to use Glide in remoteViews?

Tags: android, notifications, android-glide, remoteview, lockscreenwidget

I'm using Glide for all loading images from server, but I'm having troubleshooting trying to set them in a correct way to notifications and RemoteControlClientCompat (that cool thing with lock screens). I am developing a music player, so every time that a song is changed the song cover from notifications has to change. I have this code and it works for the first time (althoug the image is load from url or from drawable), but not when it is called for second time. The image doesn't change! CustomNotification is invoked when a song is changed. And RegisterRemoteClient is invoked on start activity.

If this is not the correct way to do it, please tell how.

```
public void CustomNotification() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Set custom notification");

    simpleRemoteView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_custom);
    expandedRemoteView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_big);

    mNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_main_logo)
            .setTicker(mSongTitle + " - " + mSongAuthors)
            .setContentTitle(mSongTitle).build();

    setRemoteListeners(simpleRemoteView);
    setRemoteListeners(expandedRemoteView);

    try {
        //Check if playingSong has a cover url, if not set one from drawable
        if(!playingSong.has("cover")){
            mDummyAlbumArt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image_song_album);
            mDummyAlbumArt2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image_song_album);
            mDummyAlbumArt3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.image_song_album);
        }else {
            Glide.with(MainActivity.context)
                    .load(API.imgUrl(playingSong.getString("cover_img")))
                    .asBitmap()
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(100, 100) {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
                            mDummyAlbumArt = bitmap;
                            mDummyAlbumArt2 = bitmap;
                            mDummyAlbumArt3 = bitmap;
                        }
                    });
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mNotification.contentView = simpleRemoteView;
    mNotification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textSongName, mSongTitle);
    mNotification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textAlbumName, mSongAuthors);
    mNotification.contentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageViewAlbumArt, mDummyAlbumArt);

    if (currentVersionSupportBigNotification) {
        mNotification.bigContentView = expandedRemoteView;
        mNotification.bigContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textSongName, mSongTitle);
        mNotification.bigContentView.setTextViewText(R.id.textAlbumName, mSongAuthors);
        mNotification.bigContentView.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageViewAlbumArt, mDummyAlbumArt2);
    }

    if (mPlayer != null) {
        if (!mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mNotification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnPlayPause, R.mipmap.play);
            if (currentVersionSupportBigNotification) {
                mNotification.bigContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnPlayPause, R.mipmap.play);
            }
        } else {
            mNotification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnPlayPause, R.mipmap.pause);
            if (currentVersionSupportBigNotification) {
                mNotification.bigContentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnPlayPause, R.mipmap.pause);
            }
        }
    }

    mNotification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    if(currentVersionSupportBigNotification) { //As priority_max only suported on API 16, the same as big notification
        mNotification.priority = Notification.PRIORITY_MAX;
    }
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, mNotification);

    //update remote controls
    if (currentVersionSupportLockScreenControls) {
        remoteControlClientCompat.editMetadata(true)
                .putString(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE, mSongTitle + " - " + mSongAuthors)
                .putBitmap(RemoteControlClientCompat.MetadataEditorCompat.METADATA_KEY_ARTWORK, mDummyAlbumArt3)
                .apply();
    }
}

public void setRemoteListeners(RemoteViews remoteViews){
    Log.d(TAG,"Setting remote listeners");
    PendingIntent piAppActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent piPlayPause = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_TOGGLE_PLAYBACK), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent piNext = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_SKIP), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent piClose = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_STOP), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent piPrevious = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PREVIOUS), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.linearLayoutNotification, piAppActivity);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPlayPause, piPlayPause);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnNext, piNext);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnDelete, piClose);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.btnPrevious, piPrevious);
}

private void RegisterRemoteClient(){
    // Use the media button APIs (if available) to register ourselves for media button
    // events

    MediaButtonHelper.registerMediaButtonEventReceiverCompat(mAudioManager, mMediaButtonReceiverComponent);
    // Use the remote control APIs (if available) to set the playback state
    if (remoteControlClientCompat == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        intent.setComponent(mMediaButtonReceiverComponent);
        remoteControlClientCompat = new RemoteControlClientCompat(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this /*context*/,0 /*requestCode, ignored*/, intent /*intent*/, 0 /*flags*/));
        RemoteControlHelper.registerRemoteControlClient(mAudioManager,remoteControlClientCompat);
    }

    remoteControlClientCompat.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
    remoteControlClientCompat.setTransportControlFlags(
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PAUSE |
                    RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PREVIOUS |
                    RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_NEXT |
                    RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_STOP);
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to set use **[NotificationTarget](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/NotificationTarget.java)** class to set your notification image as glide target

```
NotificationTarget notificationTarget = new NotificationTarget(  
    context,
    R.id.iv_album_art,
    remoteView,
    notification,
    NOTIFICATION_ID);
```

and then use that target in usual glide way

```
    Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(PlayerConstants.sArtworkUri,
        mediaitem.getAlbumId());

    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()) 
    .asBitmap()
    .load(uri)
    .into(notificationTarget);
```

It is explained in Glide's guideline  here

https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-loading-images-into-notifications-and-appwidgets

You might also like to animate album art change- Its described here:-

https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-custom-animations-with-animate