# android notification update issue with remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap()

Tags: android, image, notifications

i'm writing a Notificator class for audio player. My notification has custom layout, so i use RemoteViews class for fill it. There are 4 ImageView (3 for buttons and 1 for cover image) and 1 TextView (for song name).

For showing my notification i use this method:

```
public void notify(final Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
            R.layout.notification);

    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.play,R.drawable.btn_pause_notification);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Intent playPreviousIntent = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PREVIOUS);
    PendingIntent pendingPlayPreviousIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, playPreviousIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.previous,pendingPlayPreviousIntent);

    Intent playPauseIntent = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_PLAYPAUSE);
    PendingIntent pendingPlayPauseIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, playPauseIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.play,pendingPlayPauseIntent);

    Intent playNextIntent = new Intent(MusicService.ACTION_NEXT);
    PendingIntent pendingPlayNextIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, playNextIntent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.next,pendingPlayNextIntent);

    Intent cancelIntent = new Intent(MusicService.CANCEL_NOTIFICATION);
    PendingIntent pendingCancelIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, cancelIntent, 0);


    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    builder.setContent(remoteViews);
    builder.setDeleteIntent(pendingCancelIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
}
```

When user clicks on Next or Previous buttons in notification my service change track and update notification using such method:

```
public void updateInfo(Context context, Bitmap cover, String title, String artist) {
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.album_cover, Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cover,64,64,false));
    String text;

    if(title == "")
        text = context.getString(R.string.unknown_song);
    else
        text = title;
    text += " - ";
    if(artist == "")
        text += context.getString(R.string.unknown_artist);
    else
        text += artist;
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.song,text);


    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,builder.build());
}
```

**Problem description:**
After several (30-40) fast (5-6 Hz) clicks on Next or Previous buttons notification freezes and stops to update.

The cause of problem is there:

```
remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.album_cover, Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cover,64,64,false));
```

As i understand this operation takes a lot of time. If i set size of cover in 25x25 all works pefectly. But 25x25 is too small for cover. So i have no idea how to do it properly. Help please.

**UPD**     I've tried to use async load with Glide as described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220142/how-to-use-glide-in-remoteviews). The result is much better, but the lags still remains.

Comment: To my understanding this is happening because of the bitmap operation. creating a scaled bitmap at that pace is causing the issue. Try to pre-scale the bitmap, at-least a next few for smoother transition.

Comment: nope, coz if i change new size to 25x25 it works fine. So, resizing procedure doesnt have effect. As i suppose remoteview needs more time for load image with more size.